# Does not contain a definition for Where and no extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

So I've looked around for awhile for the answer to my problem, and I'm seeing to add `using System.Linq`, except I already have that there so I don't know what my code isn't compiling. In my context of code, `_accountreader` exists, so why is it saying no definition of it exists?

The line `return _accountReader.Where(x => x.Age);` is where the compiler yells at me.

```
public interface IAccountReader
{
    IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountFrom(string file);
}

public class XmlFileAccountReader : IAccountReader
{
    public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountFrom(string file)
    {
        var accounts = new List<Account>();
        //read accounts from XML file
        return accounts;
    }
}

public class AccountProcessor
{
    private readonly IAccountReader _accountReader;
    public AccountProcessor(IAccountReader accountReader)
    {
        _accountReader = accountReader;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountFrom(string file)
    {
        return _accountReader.Where(x => x.Age);
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `IAccountReader` does not implement `IEnumerable<Account>`.

Comment: I already have that. I said it in the first paragraph explaining my problem. :(

Comment: To put Tim's comment in everyday terms, `_accountReader` is *one* account reader. `Where` operates on *collections* of items, so what you have written there makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IAccountReader` does not implement `IEnumerable<Account>`.

Since you have provided a method `GetAccountFrom` you could also use this:

```
public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccountFrom(string file)
{
    return _accountReader.GetAccountFrom(file).Where(x => x.Age);
}
```

Apart from that the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is incorrect, you need to provide a predicate, for example:

```
.Where(x => x.Age <= 10);
```

Comment: Tim, you are a genius. Thank you so much! I will make it the correct answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me. :D.

And thank you also to everyone else that tried helping.

Answer (score 3):

You can add System.Linq namespace.  Since where has been developed under this namespace, it should be added.

Comment: OP stated in question "`using System.Linq` ... I already have that there" and accepted an answer which fixed his code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to implement this:

```
public class AccountProcessor
{    
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<int> GetAgesFrom(string file)
    {
        return _accountReader.GetAccountFrom(file).Where(x => x.Age);
    }
}
```